# Onclick doesn't work on supports

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, onclick, device

I created a list of 5 videos with an onclick function. When a user click on one of its, the video will replaced the main video on the top of the website. 
This is my code. It works to Chrome, IE9+, Firefox but not in Smartphone and Tablet. Actually when i try on iphone and android mobile, the function onclick doesn't work and no video appears except sometimes but it is not the good one but the main video that plays automatically when loading the home page.

HTML :

```
  <div id="videox">    
      <div class="carousel carousel-stage">
          <div id="video">
               <div class="flowplayer" data-engine="flash">
                     <div id="css-poster" class="flowplayer minimalist" style="">
                      <video id="videoliste" autoplay >     
                            <source src="video/webdoc_bout_a_bout_rmk.mp4" type="video/mp4; codecs=avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2" /> 
                      </video> 
                     </div>
                </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>


<ul>
    <li><img src="photos/p1.png" onclick="afficheliste1('liste1_1')"></li>
    <li><img src="photos/p2.png" onclick="afficheliste1('liste1_2')"></li>
    <li><img src="photos/p3.png" onclick="afficheliste1('liste1_3')"></li>
    <li><img src="photos/p4.png" onclick="afficheliste1('liste1_4')"></li>
    <li><img src="photos/p5.png" onclick="afficheliste1('liste1_5')"></li>
</ul>
```

JS :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var n_video=1;
function afficheliste1(x)
            {
                document.getElementById('videox').style.display = 'block';
                var objet=document.getElementById('videoliste');
                if(objet)
                {
                    objet.src="video/"+x+".mp4";
                    n_video=x.charAt(6);
                }
            }
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a `ontouchend="afficheliste1('liste1_1')"` on your `<img>` tag to make it work on mobile browsers.